# AS3 enemy spawns on top of the previous one

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop

so this is my first time here. Have looked around if this question has been answered, and it has, but not clear enough for me. Sorry for the potential double post.

I am trying to get enemies on the screen. They spawn at random positions, as you can see below, but... they spawn on top of their previous spawned enemy. The answers I read include putting it into an array, but I did, right? I'm a bit confused and working on this for too long, might be that too.

Thanks in advance!

```
function enemySpawn(e:TimerEvent) {
var enemyAxis:int = Math.round(Math.random()); // determines the x or y axis (0 or 1)
var enemyPos1:int = Math.round(Math.random()) * 600; // spawning it outside the stage (0 or 600)
var enemyPos2:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600); // spawning it at random around the stage border (0 through 600)

// spawning the enemy at correct axis
addChild(_enemy);
if(enemyAxis == 0){
    // we declare 0 = x-axis, then either position 0 or max-width, plus the enemy's width.
    _enemy.x = enemyPos1;
    _enemy.y = enemyPos2;
} else
if(enemyAxis == 1){
    // we declare 1 = y-axis, then either position 0 or max-height, plus the enemy's height.
    _enemy.y = enemyPos1;
    _enemy.x = enemyPos2;
}

enemyContainer.push(_enemy);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I understood you correctly, but calling `addChild` is not enough to create a new instance of `MovieClip`. It just adds it to the target container (or does nothing, if the MC is already in that container).

If you want to spawn several enemies simultaneously, you should create new instances of your MC using the `new` keyword prior to calling `addChild`:

```
var enemy:MovieClip = new Enemy();
addChild(enemy);
// _enemies is an array/vector that contains all created enemies;
// it is not necessary, but helps to access the enemy later, when
// the call of enemySpawn() function inside which the enemy was created
// has ended
_enemies.push(enemy);
```

To be able to do this, you'll need to enable AS3 linkage for the Enemy symbol in the Library. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13355758/804678).

Comment: Thanks! But no, that wasn't the problem. I already used AS linkage. The problem was that I had my _enemy variable set up outside of the function, so it didn't copy it; it constantly edited it. I now have it declared in the function itself, so every enemy is a new variable, added to the container array.