# When I drag a circle movie clip to stage from library in Flash, am I creating an object? If so, what's the class? Can I write the whole thing in code?

Tags: class, actionscript-3, flash, object, actionscript

Let's say I created a blue circle, converted the symbol to movie clip and named it "blue".

So **Am I making a new class named "blue", with all the properties of movie clip?**

Now the blue circle movie clip I just created is in the library. Now suppose, I dragged the blue circle from the library to the stage, gave it an instance name "blue_1".

**Did I just create an object "blue_1" of the class "blue".**

If I wrote the whole thing in code (without dragging the blue circle from the library to stage), should it be like this --

```
var blue_1:blue = new blue();
```

and we could access the blue circle on the stage now as --

```
blue_1.x = 500;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a MovieClip from the library to the stage programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353908/how-to-add-a-movieclip-from-the-library-to-the-stage-programmatically)

Comment: But yes, this is exactly correct.

Comment: As a side note, it is convention to name classes with a leading capital letter and instances with a leading lower case letter.

Comment: with the caveat that you need a linkage name for your library symbol (they explain it in the other question), your reasoning is correct