# Bitmap from Library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I looked this up on Google and watched a video, but this doesn't work for me.

When I try to link a symbol in the library with an AS Linkage, then attach it to a BitmapData variable, this error code shows:

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 4   1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Gun to an unrelated type flash.display:BitmapData.

I don't use bitmap or bitmapdata much, and I don't use classes much, so I have no idea what is wrong. This is my code:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var gun:BitmapData = new Gun;
```

And this is my advanced properties for the symbol:

Export for ActionScript = true

Export in frame 1 = true

Class = Gun

(I do not have a file named Gun)

Base Class = flash.display.MovieClip

I do not know what *I* am doing wrong, because I looked at multiple videos and websites saying that this works.

Can somebody help me? Am I writing the code incorrectly, or is something wrong with my settings?

Comment: What if you assign `Bitmap` as the base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare it as BitmapData - BitmapData is just raw bitmap data :)

Since you have declared MovieClip as Base Class, this should become a MovieClip:

```
var gun:MovieClip = new Gun();
```

If your gun has no timeline (so it's a graphics with just one frame), set the Base Class to Sprite and handle it as sprite - this is better for memory and performance:

```
var gun:Sprite = new Gun();
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this as a bitmap? I've never used sprites, so could I just change a sprite when I wanted to?

Comment: @ZaneClark, there is a pen icon next to your comment for editing (within first 5 minutes of posting). Anyways declare a new `bitmap` and a new `bitmapdata` then use for example as : `yourBMPdata.draw( gun );`. There are plenty tutorials about AS3 bitmapdata on the web.

Comment: Well you could convert Sprite to BitmapData but what's the point? You can scale and position a sprite but not bitmapdata. If you need another Sprite you just use another one, it depends on the usage. Your Gun Symbol must have the linkage name "Gun". Take a look here for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353908/how-to-add-a-movieclip-from-the-library-to-the-stage-programmatically