# Spawning Objects in AS3? (dont have actual codes)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been self-studying AS3 and was planning to make a simple game where you will pick some stone and then get points. The problem is that in my knowledge(AS3/Flash) I can just simply make more stone and then put it in the stage which it makes the game predictable and boring since their place are in one position and also it makes my script messy since i have to name those stone objects that I created.

I done some research and I found out about arrays and it actually makes it more organized but the problem is i don't really understand how it works like how do you link a symbol to it like for example:

I draw a box>Convert it to a symbol(movie clip)>named it stone.
Then i create a big circle>convert it to a symbol(graphic)>named it bgSpace.
let's assume the size of bgSpace is 300px(can be lower or higher if its too big or small)

now what i want is to have bgSpace spawn stone randomly in its space and then when the stone is clicked/picked it will disappear and then you get 1 point but i have no idea how to code it.

So if I will make this with my knowledge I'll just leave bgSpace and then put many stone in that area and then name them stone1, stone2, and so on. And code it like this:

```
var pick = 0;
var total = 0;

this.stone1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stoneGet);
this.stone2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stoneGet);
this.stone3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stoneGet);
this.stone4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stoneGet);

function stoneGet(event:MouseEvent):void
{
pick = pick + 1;
total = total + 1;
if (pick == 4)
{
gotoAndStop(2);//Indicated you move to next level
}
}//no need to check this and correct if i made an error this is just a sample on my logic
```

I saw some articles and the most common things i saw is this kind of code

```
var thing:Array = new Array[4];//what i understand var = variable, thing = name of array or name of symbol?, :Array indication its an array?, = new Array[4] = making an array with 4 slot?

function makeThing() {//function

addChild(thing);//add the symbol?
thing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeThing);
}

function removeThing(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.pick();
    removeChild(event.target);// does this remove the symbol? and where do you type the code where you add 1 point per pick.
}
```

I migt confuse you people but what i want is a way to link symbol to arrays it really confuse me. Also I want in every time you start the game the placement of stones will be changed/it is randomized. I read few articles and made me new questions everytime i read one so i thought of asking here first then move on so that i will not bypass or forgot some details i want to learn. I might not be available to reply since im going to sleep, Thanks in Advance and Information.

Comment: This will help you to understand how to create new objects from Library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353908/how-to-add-a-movieclip-from-the-library-to-the-stage-programmatically Also, you might want to Google > as3 instantiate movieclip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Introduction to Arrays

A variable is much like a container in the physical world. If I have an object in a container, I can take it out and place it anywhere or do anything with it, virtually regardless of what object may be in that container. I don't necessarily need to know anything about the object or even have a general idea of what it is. This applies in code as well, and is an especially common way of working with arrays.

An array can be thought of as a container with infinite compartments. Inside an array, each compartment is assigned an ID - commonly referred to as an "index" or "key" (remember this!) - and we can use this to identify the compartment that we want to access.

This is a simple example of making and reading an array of strings in AS3:

```
var myArray:Array = new Array('first value here', 'this is the second entry', 'just another string');
trace(myArray);
```

In the debug log this will print out:

```
first value here,this is the second entry,just another string
```

Each item or entry in an array is typically referred to as an "element". We can access these elements individually as well. For example, building on the previous example:

```
trace(myArray[0]);
```

Will output:

```
first value here
```

What's going on here? Well, every element in an array automatically has a number assigned to it, sequentially, starting from zero. Here is a visual representation of our array now:

```
--------------------------------------
|                  0                 |
|          first value here          |
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
|                  1                 |
|      this is the second entry      |
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
|                  2                 |
|         just another string        |
--------------------------------------
```

...and we use square brackets `[]` to access any element by its index. What will we get if we run `trace(myArray[1])`? You guessed it: `this is the second entry`

## Sprites/Movieclips in Arrays

So, how do we put something into our array? Well, this is done in three ways, and you don't have to use just one. The most appropriate method will depend on what you're trying to build.

1. Through initialization:

   `var myArray:Array = new Array('moose', 'newspaper', 'smoothie');`
2. Through explicit assignment:

   `var myArray:Array = new Array();
   myArray[5] = 'potato';`
3. Through the `push` function:

   `var myArray:Array = new Array();
   myArray.push('This is my data. Guard it with your life.');`

When using the `push` function, your new element will be assigned the index with the largest number in your array, plus 1. For example, if `myArray[0]` is already being used, our new element will be assigned to `myArray[1]`.

Arrays are powerful and we can use them to store any kind of data. While it's generally best avoided, we can even mix the types of data we store in an array. For example, take a look at this:

```
var myArray:Array = new Array('squirrel', 7, true);
```

This code is completely valid and will store a string, int, and boolean in their native formats.

We can store *any* kind of objects in an array, including Sprites and MovieClips, using the same syntax as in all previous examples:

```
myArray.push(myMovieClip);
```

## Making New MovieClips On The Fly

Before we load our array with MovieClips (rocks in your case) and scatter them around the screen, we need to learn how to generate new ones.

Every "copy" you make of a MovieClip is referred to as an "instance". Actually calling them a "copy" isn't the best way to describe them. They're more like "clones" in the sense that they can all be animated and made to be interacted with completely independently of each other.

To generate a new instance the process is simple. We only need to tell Flash what MovieClip we want to generate. Naturally we need some kind of name or ID for our MovieClip so Flash can know which one we want to use. If you're using purely code-oriented software for developing in AS3 such as FlashDevelop, or Eclipse, you will already know where to find the name of your MovieClip. However, if you're using Adobe's Flash Pro the first step is different.

I haven't used Adobe's Flash Pro in a long time, however I believe that the process should still be extremely similar. Assuming you've already converted your object to a symbol, these are the steps:

1. Open the Library panel from the `Window -> Library` menu, if it is not already open.
2. Click to select the MovieClip you'd like to make instances of so that it is highlighted in the list of the Library panel.
3. Expand the "Advanced" section if it is not already open.
4. Enable "Export for Actionscript".
5. Enable "Export in frame 1" if it is not already enabled. (this means your MovieClip can be used with ActionScript as soon as your game loads, rather than only once you use it somewhere on the timeline)
6. Enter the name you'd like to use for your MovieClip, in the "Class" text box. By default this will be set to be the same as the name of your MovieClip itself which is generally preferred, but you do have a choice here. (In AS3, when choosing class names, it's generally considered good practice to use upper camel case, without symbols, and never beginning in a number. Good: `Rock`, `BigPizza`, `Jersey11`. Bad: `rock`, `bigPizza`, `11Jersey`, 'Mashed_Potatoes`)
7. Press "OK" and let out a little cheer as you're now ready to start generating instances of your MovieClip in ActionScript.

## Generating Instances

From now on I'll assume you've set the "Class" name of your MovieClip to "Rock".

Let's make an instance:

```
new Rock();
```

Voila! That was too easy, right? Right. If you run your script you'll notice that there is no new MovieClip on the screen; we need to add the MovieClip to the *stage*.

Anything and everything displayed within your Flash movie (or game/video/app if you prefer) is on the *stage*. We can think of this much like an actual stage in a theater. Even if we make a new instance of our MovieClip it can't be seen until we place it on the stage. Here's how we can put a rock on the stage:

```
addChild(new Rock());
```

This will work just fine, but it's not usually a very elegant or organized way of doing it, because we don't have an easy way to refer to our instance if we want to do something to it (like move it around).

Instead what we should do is put our instance into a variable like so:

```
var myRock:Rock = new Rock();
addChild(myRock);
```

Now we can refer to it by name:

```
// Here we place our instance 50 pixels from the left edge of the stage:
myRock.x = 50;
```

Now we've encountered the issue you've mentioned in your post: what do I do about naming all these rocks I want to toss about? Clearly writing a line of code for each and every rock is not very efficient. What if I want to make a rock farm simulation and I need 100 rocks? There is a common and easy-to-use solution to this predicament: *Arrays*!

But that's not the whole story; we need to learn to generate instances of MovieClips without naming them, and the way to do that is through *loops*.

### Loops

I won't go into great detail on writing loops. Their syntax may seem strange at first, however once you get past that the concept is very simple. Play with them until you feel comfortable in your understanding of them.

Their syntax is as follows:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment expression) {
    // The code you want to repeat goes here
}
```

Now, that might not make a lot of sense by itself, so let's look at some *real* code:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // The code you want to repeat goes here
    trace ('This is iteration number ' + i);
}
```

Here's what's happening:

```
   |initialization|condition|increment expression|
     vvvvvvvvvvvvv  vvvvvvv  vvvv
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) {...
```

1. We create the variable `i` with the initial value of `0`.
2. The condition is checked at the beginning of every loop and the loops runs if the condition evaluates to `true`.
3. The last part, "increment expression", runs at the end of every loop. `i++` is a shorter way of writing `i = i + 1`.

So, in other words, our loop begins by setting `i` to `0`, then increasing `i` by 1 after every loop and each time checking that `i` is smaller than `100`. Since `i` starts at `0` this means our loop will run exactly 100 times.

### Loops and Arrays

We can use a loop to fill an array with any number of MovieClips like this:

```
var myMovieClips:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myMovieClips[i] = new Rock();
    addChild(myMovieClips[i]);
}
```

Notice that we use `myMovieClips[i]` to refer to the last instance we made. We can use a variable's value as a way to refer to a specific index in our array. So if `i = 5`, then `myMovieClips[i]` is the same as `myMovieClips[5]`.

Congratulations! You can generate instances!

## Bonus: Scattering The Rocks

All of our MovieClips are being created in the exact same spot; the top-left corner of the stage. This is because the `x` and `y` properties of the MovieClips are all set to `0` by default.

We can scatter them using some simple functions and math. For this example let's assume our stage is 1,000 pixels wide and 1,000 pixels tall. We need to generate a number between 0 and 1,000 for our MovieClip's `x` and `y` coordinates. We can use the `random` function of the `Math` class to generate a decimal number from 0 to 1 like so:

```
Math.random();
```

To make the value between 0 and 1,000 instead we just need to multiply it:

```
Math.random() * 1000;
```

You don't actually need to know how big your stage is, because the size is set in the `stageHeight` and `stageWidth` properties of the `stage` object. So, to set our MovieClips at random positions when we generate the instances, our final code would look like this:

```
var myMovieClips:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myMovieClips[i] = new Rock();
    myMovieClips[i].x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    myMovieClips[i].y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    addChild(myMovieClips[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps!